# How to re order DF Using pd.Categorical?

Tags: python, pandas

Having a `DF`

| Test | WGT |
| --- | --- |
| TOTO | 5 |
| TATA | 7 |
| TZTZ | 1 |

doing :

```
DF['Test'] = pd.Categorical(DF['Test'],categories = ["TATA","TZTZ","TOTO"],ordered=True)
```

but when I do :

```
print(DF)
```

I still have the same DF :

| Test | WGT |
| --- | --- |
| TOTO | 5 |
| TATA | 7 |
| TZTZ | 1 |

Where the excepted output is :

| Test | WGT |
| --- | --- |
| TATA | 7 |
| TZTZ | 1 |
| TOTO | 5 |

What am I doing wrong there ?

It seems to me that index has not been reseted :

```
print(DF.Test)
#returns
0       TOTO
1       TATA
2       TZTZ
    Name: Test, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): ['TATA' < 'TZTZ' < 'TOTO']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the values ordered, not sorted.

Now you need to [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)!

```
DF2 = DF.sort_values(by='Name')
```

output:

```
   Name  WGT
1  TATA    7
2  TZTZ    1
0  TOTO    5
```

Comment: Many thanks, will accept when It is possible